# FB.ui feed dialog is "ignoring" the picture attribute, using cached og:image tag instead

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed, image, fb.ui

Here's my FB.ui code:

```
FB.ui({ 
  method: 'feed', 
  message: '', 
  link: 'http://mywebaddress/pathToContent', 
  picture: 'http://mywebaddress/pathToPhoto/photo.jpg', 
  display: 'popup'
});
```

The dialog pops up perfectly, it has the link so no problem... but the picture doesn't show.

I have verified the picture URL is correct. Then I have used the Debugger to test the content URL's open graph tags: it runs flawlessly.

Apparently, the debugger clears some sort of caching. After I use the debugger on the link, the `FB.ui` dialog shows the picture just fine.

Is there something I can do about this? The content that users are sharing from my site to Facebook isn't showing the picture like it should, making it a bit annoying for them to use (which is never a good thing!)

Thanks!

Comment: You are saying that using the debugger solves the problem? so it's a caching issue...

Comment: OK, so the url "graph stuff" is being cached without a photo even though from inception the page has had a valid og:image tag? And, the FB.ui code, even when provided a picture attribute, ignores it and instead uses the no photo cache? If it's a caching issue, sounds like it would be on Fb's side, how to get around it?

Comment: Have you tried submitting the `FB.ui` dialog? even if the image is not shown there...is it shown when you publish? if so, then I would assume there's something wrong in the dialog

Comment: I have tried submitting it... I just updated my code, to make the picture attribute url slightly different than what the og:image tag has... I added ?v=1 to the path, after the picture's file extension.

So far, this has made it better... but still testing. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `og:image` in the source of the shared url instead. The `picture` parameter is deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/#response

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you didn't set the URL of your image.

```
Since you're using a relative URL, the FB.ui is looking for the image in the same folder as the current page. What you should do is put the full URL of your image.

<code>picture: 'http://mywebaddress/pathToPhoto/photo.jpg',</code>
If you don't have the full URL of your image, you can use the following code to get the full URL:
<code>var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
url += 'pathToPhoto/photo.jpg';
</code>
```